# Use Twitter API in China

Tags: python, api, twitter

I have a problem when reading the book [Mining the Social Web](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1449388345) because I live in China and we can't access Twitter due to government internet filtering.

I got stuck when testing this example in chapter 1-3:

```
`import twitter`

`twitter_search = twitter.Twitter(domain="api.twitter.com")`

`trends = twitter_search.trends()`
```

It stops here.

I tried a Twitter API proxy, but still couldn't get the data using the Twitter Api.

Comment: This is a question for HackExchange :)

Comment: i want to get twitter data under shell , it seems impossible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to use a VPN outside your country or maybe try out [Tor](https://www.torproject.org/). No guarantees that it's not illegal in the People's republic of China, though.

I suffer with you.

Comment: I can't change where i born ~~

Answer (score 0):

I hope you don't get into trouble for this. What about using [TOR](https://www.torproject.org/) with a proxy? It is build to circumvent censorship.

Comment: thanks,i can visit twitter through ssh , the problem is i want to get twitter data under ubuntu shell, is it possible？

Comment: @shch1289: I don't know about twitter data but I have a ubuntu + tor + polipo setup here that works great.

Answer (score 0):

An old question, but I'll provide an alternate solution, which will work for any services China is censoring.

The open source Python [sshuttle](https://github.com/apenwarr/sshuttle) program is touted as the `poor man's VPN` and I love that I can use it without needing to buy any commercial services. Further to this, any paid VPN providers or publicly searchable proxy lists are just as easily discovered and subsequently blocked by Chinese authorities.

The program will turn any server you have SSH access to into your own transparent proxy server supporting DNS tunneling.

Usage is as simple as:

`./sshuttle --dns -vvr username@sshserver 0/0`

From that point on, **all** your web, telnet, FTP, chat and other traffic will be proxied through the server. No need for any additional control panels or such. It is written in Python and so can be run from Linux, Mac or Windows equally well.

If you have a web server with SSH access in the United States, all your traffic will seem to originate from this point, giving the added benefit that you can also utilize US-only internet services.

Note, this will work for any services blocked in China, such as Twitter, YouTube, Facebook, Wikipedia, etc.

I've also found this to greatly improve and stabilize my internet speed whilst using in China, though some local Chinese services such as QQ became slower.